# File transfer from iOS App to Mac App?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, file-transfer

Is it possible to transfer files between a Mac app and a iOS app? I want to transfer files that are in the documents directory in my iOS App to my Mac App via Wifi, how could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as of iOS 5 onwards, there's iCloud. Since that's still under NDA, I'll just have to point to the [relevant documentation](http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php) and let you read up on your own.

If not, I'd consider using the fabulous [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) APIs. This does require your users signing up for a Dropbox account, but then you get automatic two-way syncing between their Mac (or PC) and their iOS devices.

Failing that, there's always [Bonjour](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Introduction.html). Properly configured - and it's not super easy, there is a bit of CFSocket or BSD socket work that you need to do - Bonjour will discover any services on the local network, Mac or iOS.

Comment: Dropbox doesn't have confict resolution mechanism. Having said that, I would recommend using Dropbox only for storing backups of your user created data and not for syncing.

Comment: Dropbox has versioning, like iCloud.

Comment: @Morgan Dropbox has versioning indeed. But there is no API as far as I remember. There is a forum question on this too. http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=40492