# ios file sharing/sync to devices from mac/pc

Tags: .net, ios, ipad, bonjour, file-sharing

I have developed the ipad app which displays images and other product details from sqlite db. 
I have also developed .net based windows application which resides on Windows xp pc. This application generates data in sqlite db and also map each record with related images. This flow is working fine till now with itunes filesharing feature enabled. 
So the user copy sqlite db and images(around 2-3 gb) to iPad through itunes file sharing.

Recently I came across Bonjour service which is used to communicate in local network.

I was wondering is it possible that my .net based application creates Bonjour server and keeps the sqlite db & images files in some folder and ios devices can directly read from that over wifi and get files when requested?

Please suggest if using Bonjour services will be good approach and any sample tutorial to start with.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [File transfer from iOS App to Mac App?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6922118/file-transfer-from-ios-app-to-mac-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After really really hard searching... found something worth using or to be worked upon.. http://syncdocs.sourceforge.net/index.php.

It uses Bonjour service to discover and further send/receive files.

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour can help you to find devices on the local network.

Then you must develop your own transfer protocol or use for example [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) for start.

Comment: Thanks. I will look in to library you specified. Bonjour service can be used to transfer files as well isn't it?

Comment: No, bonjour is just a discovery service.

Comment: After really really hard searching... found something worth using or to be worked upon.. http://syncdocs.sourceforge.net/index.php. It uses Bonjour service to discover and further send/receive files.

Comment: syncdocs is just a ready to use implementation of the library, that uses bonjour as discovery service and a web server for the real transfer

Comment: yes and that what I was looking for. :) I understood that Bonjour is only device discovery service.