# Share folder between Mac app and iOS app

Tags: ios, macos, cocoahttpserver

How can I share a folder between a Mac app (sender) and a iOS app (receiver)?

Are there any high-level APIs to do this? Or should I use something like [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)?

Comment: What do you mean, a folder?

Comment: Access contents of a folder/directory: list files, download files. I only need read-only access.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365026/ios-file-sharing-sync-to-devices-from-mac-pc

Comment: @noa That link simply suggests to use the discovery service Bonjour. I wondered if there was something higher level to deal with file sharing between Apple devices.

Comment: One answer suggests a framework called SyncDocs. The other answer says, "no, start with Bonjour, then write your own protocol."